# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Constraint (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the Module context

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

Getting the error :

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the
> CompanyExistsConstraint (?). Please make sure that the argument
> dependency at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.
>
> Potential solutions: If dependency is a provider, is it part of the
> current UsersModule? If dependency is exported from a separate
> @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?@Module({
> imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]})

I have added some custom class-validators validatorConstraints in the DTO for validations

My users.module.ts code:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { userSchema } from './entities/user.entity';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { DynamooseModule } from 'nestjs-dynamoose';
import { DBName } from '../constants/DB';
import { CompanyExistsConstraint } from './validators/company.validators';
import { RoleExistConstraint } from './validators/role.validators';
import { PhoneAlreadyExistConstraint } from './validators/phonenumber.validators';
import { EmailAlreadyExistConstraint } from './validators/email.validators';
@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  imports: [
    DynamooseModule.forFeature([{ name: DBName, schema: userSchema }]),
    HttpModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    UsersService,
    CompanyExistsConstraint,
    RoleExistConstraint,
    PhoneAlreadyExistConstraint,
    EmailAlreadyExistConstraint,
  ],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

One of the constraints that uses `UsersService`:

```js
import {
  registerDecorator,
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
  ValidationArguments,
} from 'class-validator';

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import { UsersService } from '../users.service';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'CompanyExists', async: true })
@Injectable()
export class CompanyExistsConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}

  async validate(value: any): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!value) return false;

    try {
      return await this.usersService.companyIdExistCheck(value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);

      return false;
    }
  }

  defaultMessage(validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): string {
    return `company provided ${validationArguments.value} not exists`;
  }
}

export function CompanyExists() {
  return function (object: any, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,

      propertyName: propertyName,

      validator: CompanyExistsConstraint,
    });
  };
}
```

Can anyone help me on this to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UsersService)) private usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}
```

Adding this inject to the constraints removed the dependency errors.

Thanks for nestjs discord community to help me spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on Discord, your constraint relies on your service which relies on your DTO which relies on your constraint. It's a circular file reference. Having your service use a `type` import (`import type { Dto } from './dto'`) should resolve that. If not, create an interface that has the same properties as the DTO but doesn't import it to break the cyclic chain.